# How to fix collision of a ball with a rect object in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm stuck with this `rect.collision()` thing in `pygame` . I'm trying to create a simple pong game but it's not working fine. There are still a lot errors but half of the game is done, ball is bouncing and paddles are moving accordingly.  But collision is a problem. Can someone fix it.

You need to keep in mind that i'm not a professional coder not even a computer science student. I'm a physics student so please be nice with coding jargon.  But I have a good knowledge of python though.
Here is my code, just copy it, run it and soon you will find errors. And one more thing, i don't want to code in object oriented way, making classes or things like this but just want to make this code work.

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()

width,height=680,450
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG GAME")
xoffset,yoffset=30,50

vel=7
radius=12

cir_x,cir_y=width/2,height/2
xvel=yvel=5

w=20
p1_x,p1_y=xoffset,height//2-yoffset
p2_x,p2_y=width-w-xoffset,height//2-yoffset
h=2*(yoffset)


leftPaddle=pygame.Rect(p1_x,p1_y,w,h)
rightPaddle=pygame.Rect(p2_x,p2_y,w,h)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

count=0
run=True
while run:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type==pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
    screen.fill(1)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255),(p1_x,p1_y,w,h))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255),(p2_x,p2_y,w,h))

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,255),(cir_x,cir_y),radius)

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_UP] and p2_y > vel:
        p2_y -= vel
    if keys[K_DOWN] and p2_y < height - h - vel:
        p2_y += vel
    if keys[K_w] and p1_y > vel:
        p1_y -= vel
    if keys[K_s] and p1_y < height - h - vel:
        p1_y += vel
    cir_x+=xvel
    cir_y+=yvel

    if (cir_x+radius>width or cir_x<radius):
        xvel*=-1
    if (cir_y+radius>height or cir_y<radius):
        yvel*=-1

    if (leftPaddle.collidepoint(cir_x,cir_y)):
        xvel*=-1

    if (rightPaddle.collidepoint(cir_x,cir_y)):
        xvel*=-1

    clock.tick(50)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure that the `pygame.Rect` objects `leftPaddle` and `rightPaddle`are located at the actual position of the paddles. The easiest way is to use `leftPaddle` and `rightPaddle` to draw and move the paddles:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255), leftPaddle)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255), rightPaddle)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,255),(round(cir_x), round(cir_y)),radius)

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_UP] and rightPaddle.top > vel:
        rightPaddle.y -= vel
    if keys[K_DOWN] and rightPaddle.bottom < height - vel:
        rightPaddle.y += vel
    if keys[K_w] and leftPaddle.top > vel:
        leftPaddle.y -= vel
    if keys[K_s] and leftPaddle.bottom < height - vel:
        leftPaddle.y += vel
    cir_x+=xvel
    cir_y+=yvel
```

Use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to evaluate if a paddel collides with the rectangle that surrounds the ball. Since the velocity of the ball is not 1, the ball can penetrate into the paddle. Restrict the position of the ball to `leftPaddle` respectively `rightPaddle`:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    ball_rect = pygame.Rect(cir_x-radius, cir_y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius)

    if leftPaddle.colliderect(ball_rect):
        cir_x = leftPaddle.right + radius
        xvel*=-1

    if rightPaddle.colliderect(ball_rect):
        cir_x = rightPaddle.left - radius
        xvel*=-1
```

---

See the complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

width,height=680,450
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG GAME")
xoffset,yoffset=30,50

vel=7
radius=12

cir_x,cir_y=width/2,height/2
xvel=yvel=5

w=20
p1_x,p1_y=xoffset,height//2-yoffset
p2_x,p2_y=width-w-xoffset,height//2-yoffset
h=2*(yoffset)

leftPaddle=pygame.Rect(p1_x,p1_y,w,h)
rightPaddle=pygame.Rect(p2_x,p2_y,w,h)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

count=0
run=True
while run:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type==pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
    screen.fill(1)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255), leftPaddle)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(225,225,255), rightPaddle)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,255),(round(cir_x), round(cir_y)),radius)

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_UP] and rightPaddle.top > vel:
        rightPaddle.y -= vel
    if keys[K_DOWN] and rightPaddle.bottom < height - vel:
        rightPaddle.y += vel
    if keys[K_w] and leftPaddle.top > vel:
        leftPaddle.y -= vel
    if keys[K_s] and leftPaddle.bottom < height - vel:
        leftPaddle.y += vel
    cir_x+=xvel
    cir_y+=yvel

    if (cir_x+radius>width or cir_x<radius):
        xvel*=-1
    if (cir_y+radius>height or cir_y<radius):
        yvel*=-1

    ball_rect = pygame.Rect(cir_x-radius, cir_y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius)

    if leftPaddle.colliderect(ball_rect):
        cir_x = leftPaddle.right + radius
        xvel*=-1

    if rightPaddle.colliderect(ball_rect):
        cir_x = rightPaddle.left - radius
        xvel*=-1

    clock.tick(50)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this code worked fine...